# Jest not able to find module react-azure-maps in unit test cases

Tags: reactjs, azure, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-maps

I am using azure map in my react application and found [this](https://react-azure-maps.vercel.app/) library which is build on the top of azure maps but when I am writing the unit test cases for the component made using this library using jest, the jest is not able to find the module - react-azure-map, though the map is successfully loading on the application. I used create-react-app for this application.

**App.tsx**

```js
import * as azureMap from "react-azure-maps";
import {
  ControlOptions,
  AuthenticationType as auth
} from "azure-maps-control";

import "./App.css";

const cameraOptions: azureMap.AzureSetCameraOptions = {
  center: [-1.9591947375679695, 52.46891727965905],
  maxBounds: [-6.0, 49.959999905, 1.68153079591, 58.6350001085],
};

const controls: azureMap.IAzureMapControls[] = [
  {
    controlName: "StyleControl",
    controlOptions: {
      mapStyles: ["road", "grayscale_light", "satellite_road_labels"],
    },
    options: {
      position:"bottom-left",
    } as ControlOptions,
  },
  {
    controlName: "ZoomControl",
    options: { position: "bottom-right" } as ControlOptions,
  },
];

const mapConfigState: azureMap.IAzureMapOptions = {
  authOptions: {
    authType: auth.subscriptionKey,
    subscriptionKey: "********************************",
    clientId: ""********************************",
  },
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="map-container" data-testid = "map-div">
      <azureMap.AzureMapsProvider>
        <div style={{ height: "600px" }}>
          <azureMap.AzureMap
            options={mapConfigState}
            controls={controls}
            cameraOptions={cameraOptions}
          ></azureMap.AzureMap>
        </div>
      </azureMap.AzureMapsProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.tsx**

```js
import { cleanup, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import Map from '.';

describe('UT for Map', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();[enter image description here][1]
  });

  test('Should render Map component', () => {
    render(<Map />);
    const mapDiv = screen.getAllByTestId(/map-div/i);
    expect(mapDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**Error**
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Yfu.png)

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?  now running into the same

Answer (score 0):

(1) add to a jest.config file:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "react-azure-maps": "<rootDir>/.jest/react-azure-maps.js"
}
```

(2) create file `.jest/react-azure-maps.js` containing stubs for what tests would need, e.g.:

```
export const AzureMapsProvider = ({ children }) => children
export const AzureMap = () => null
```

(3) the `jest` should now pass through this issue,